# How to Check value in JSON object ionic2

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

How to check `"no_cover"` value in `thumbnail[0]` and replace it to `asset/sss.jpg` for show `listpage`
I try to set `<img src="{{item.LINKS.thumbnail[0]}}">` in Listpage.html ,this show only thumbnail[0] is `http://xxx.jpg`, `http://xxx.jpg` ,  ,But I have no idea to set "no_cover"

**myjson**

```
"    DOCSET":{
      "DOC":[
       {
        "LINKS":{

          "thumbnail":"http://yyy.jpg",
          "thumbnail":"http://....jpg"}
        }],
      "DOC":[
       {
        "LINKS":{

          "thumbnail":"http://xxx.jpg",
          "thumbnail":"http://....jpg"}
        }],
      "DOC":[
        {
        "LINKS":{

          "thumbnail":"no_cover",     <<<<
          "thumbnail":"http://....jpg"}
        }]
     }
```

---

**EDIT - HOW YOUR JSON SHOULD LOOK**

Since I (ivaro18) believe you wrote your JSON by hand and did not copy a response object. Let me show you what valid JSON looks like:

```
{
    "DOCSET" : [
        {
            "DOC" : {
                "LINKS" : [
                    {
                      "thumbnail" : "http://.....jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "thumbnail" : "http://.....jpg"
                    }                
                ]
             }
        },
        {
            "DOC" : {
                "LINKS" : [
                    {
                      "thumbnail" : "http://.....jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "thumbnail" : "http://.....jpg"
                    }                
                ]
             }
        },
        {
            "DOC" : {
                "LINKS" : [
                    {
                      "thumbnail" : "no_cover"
                    },
                    {
                      "thumbnail" : "http://.....jpg"
                    }                
                ]
             }
        }
    ]
}
```

**END OF EDIT**

---

**listpage.html**

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of foundRepos">
     <ion-thumbnail item-left  >
      <img src="{{item.LINKS.thumbnail[0]}}">  <!--I have no idea to set it -->
    </ion-thumbnail>
</ion-list>
```

list.page.ts

```
this.http.get("my_url")
 .subscribe(data =>{
     this.foundRepos = data.json().DOCSET.DOC; 
                   },error=>{
                 err => console.error(err),
                () => console.log('getRepos completed')
            );
```

Comment: Your JSON appears to be broken: you have 3 open square brackets `[` without corresponding closing brackets `]`

Comment: @elf337 oh i edited! , Can you help me T^T

Comment: Your JSON seems to have dupilcate keys `DOC`, which make it invalid and impossible to work with properly.

Comment: fongfuse, using `[...]` declares a list, `{...}` declares an object. An object can't have 2 or more things with the same name (like your `DOC` and `thumbnail` suggests). It seems like you've written the JSON by hand and mixed up the `[]` and `{}` :)

Comment: @Ivaro18  i edited! , Can you help me T^T

Comment: Like @ivaro18 says, you cannot have a key of `["LINKS": {}]` This is an invalid JSON string.

Comment: @Martin  I edited! , Can you help me T^T

Comment: Edited your question with what **should** be your JSON, should've been a comment and I know that but it would become way too complex to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first of all your JSON you've posted was invalid. edited your question with what it probably is (since you **are** printing it as you say)

What I understand from your problem is the following, you have `<img src="{{item.LINKS.thumbnail[0]}}">` but this throws a `404` when `no_cover` is returned, that's why, when `item.LINKS.thumbnail[0]` is equal to `'no_cover'` you want to show the image `assets/sss.jpg`

So, how can we use this to show `'assets/sss.jpg'` instead of `'no_cover'`? It's called the [Elvis operator ( ? : )](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator)

Let's assume the following construction for an `if`-statement:

> ```
> if(expression) {
>     result = whenExpressionIsTrue
>  } else {
>     result = whenExpressionIsFalse  
>  }
> ```

Which we can rewrite with the Elvis operator like this:

> `result = someExpression ? whenExpressionIsTrue : whenExpressionIsFalse`

So, let's check out your problem, how can we do this with an `if`-statement?

```
if(item.LINKS.thumbnail[0] == 'no_cover') {
   someVariable = 'assets/sss.jpg';
}  else {
   someVariable == item.LINKS.thumbnail[0];
}
```

Now shorten it with the Elvis operator:

```
someVariable = item.LINKS.thumbnail[0] == 'no_cover' ? 'assets/sss.jpg' : item.LINKS.thumbnail[0];
```

Now this can be used in your HTML like so:

```
<img 
     [src]="item.LINKS.thumbnails[0] == 'no_cover' ? 'assets/sss.jpg' : item.LINKS.thumbnails[0]"
/>
```

Comment: this looks better in my opinion, you can also use an if statement as long as you use the data binding `[src]` (or `[attr.src]` not entirely sure anymore) Like `[src]="if(....) { 'assets/sss.jpg' } else {  .... }`